# How to truncate seconds in TSQL?

Tags: t-sql, datetime

I have time, select cast(SYSDATETIME() AS time)
14:59:09.2834595

What is the way to truncate seconds?
14:59

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Description

You can use the T-SQL function `convert`.

#### Sample

```
PRINT convert(varchar(5), SYSDATETIME(), 108)
```

will give you `hh:mm`

#### More Information

- [MSDN - CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to truncate seconds and still have a T-SQL Date datatype, first convert the date into minutes from the date '0' and then add the minutes back to '0'. This answer doesn't require any additional parsing/converting. This method works to truncate other parts just change MINUTE.
Example:
`SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, '2016-01-01 23:22:56.997'), 0)`

Comment: I'm amazed that the other answers all cast the date to various strings instead of this simple and straightforward solution.

Comment: Spot on solution

Answer (score 1):

```
select cast(left(cast(SYSDATETIME() AS time), 5) as time)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to drop seconds off entirely, you can use the DATEPART() function (SQL Server) to strip out the hour and minute, then append it back together.  (I like dknaack's solution more, if that works.)

```
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(hour, SYSDATETIME()) + ':' + DATEPART(minute, SYSDATETIME()) AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FORMAT(time_column, 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:00.000Z') from table
```

Comment: Please be careful... the FORMAT() function is at least 17 times slower than just about any other method you might come up with using CONVERT().

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.