# SQL Server - Check if given date+time is between two datetime variables by exact date+time

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have two datetime columns in a DB table: @Start and @End.

Both columns contain the date and time, for example:

```
@Start: 2018-10-01 19:00:00
@End: 2018-10-10 23:59:00
```

I want to know if the **current date** is exactly between both datetimes considering the dates and the times.

So, `2018-10-08 16:37` and `2018-10-10 23:59:00` would match this range
and `2018-10-11 00:00:00` would not.
(In this case this date is one minute later than the End date, so it is not between my datetime range).

```
SELECT Id FROM Table1 WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN Start AND End
```

I don't use GETDATE() in real code, I use an argument. The problem is that current date argument may contain seconds and milliseconds like `23:59:59.123`. My code treats such date as not conforming given range. But I don't care about s/ms.

Is there a workaround?

### Update:

The **precision** I want to achieve is in **minutes**. So I do not even need to take in account the seconds nor the milliseconds. The date time format I would be working on would be 'yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm' but I do not know how to use the BETWEEN clause converting the Start and End to the shown format so I can compare the dates.

Comment: Your code should work in any version of SQL Server.

Comment: What happens if getdate() is _exactly_ `2018-10-10 23:59:00` down to the last ms?

Comment: Can you explain what the issues are with using a `BETWEEN` clause. It is inclusive, so if the date and time exactly matches `Start` or `End` it will evaluate to true. If you don't want that, you can use `GetDate() > Start AND GetDate() < End`.

Comment: in your example of a non-match - the time is 1 MINUTE after the time range, not one second.  Also, when you say 'not working', is it hard to know what GetDate was when the code ran?

Comment: Here In your query - `GetDate()`  always returns Current DateTime. But in order to fetch records from your table use your table column not `GetDate()`.

Comment: Between is really awful, especially when it comes to datetime checks. Here is a great discussion on the topic. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: `had issues displaying the correct answer` what is a _correct answer_ here? Yes, current date is between those Start and End dates. What is the output of your query and what is wrong with it? Share sample data for `Table1` and desired output.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I wrote a clear example in the question. The problem is that BETWEEN and other methods I tried round the datetimes so they also include records that are a minute/second lower or higher than the wanted range. I need to check if the date and time are EXACTLY in the given range including the date and time not a second more and not a second less

Comment: @user2932057  The query checks if the current date (now) is EXACTLY between the given range. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: @SalmanA If getdate() is exactly 2018-10-10 23:59:00 down to the last ms then it should be included

Comment: @asaf your query is perfect. The only possible issue is when the datatype of variables is `datetime` and you try to shove a millisecond value such as `00:00:00.001` or `00:00:00.002`. Such values get rounded and you end up with `00:00:00.000` or `00:00:00.003`.

Comment: Ah, that's what it is all about. The _last ms_. Does your `EndDate` cover those milliseconds? No. (PS does your question tell us anything about _milliseconde_, or given sample data? I'm afraid not.) Common solution is to use `<` of next date's '00:00:00' instead of fighting for `<=` with 23.59.59.(9).

Comment: @IvanStarostinYou are right, I didn't mention what depth of accuracy I want to achieve. THe max accuracy is minutes. Not seconds nor ms. Only minutes.

Comment: @SalmanA Strangely I struggled making the BETWEEN work for me. Because I want a minute precission I have to take the 'Start' and 'End' and convert them to a 'yyyy-MM-ss hh:mm' format. Am I correct? How do I do that without converting the dates into strings?

Comment: have you tried using dateadd to subtract the millisecond and second parts off?  I've never tried that though

Comment: @Cato I tried it in another solution when I compared only dates and it worked great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would seem to want this logic:

```
WHERE GETDATE() >= Start
  AND GETDATE() < DATEADD(minute, 1, End)
```

Assuming that the time part of `End` is `23:59:00` it covers all possible values between `23:59:00` and `23:59:59.999...999`.

Comment: I took your advice and it worked! Thank you very much!
Also the BETWEEN solution also seemed to work after all.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT Id FROM Table1 WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN '2018-10-01 19:00:00' AND '2018-10-10 23:59:00'

Comment: A little explanation of why this works would make this better.

Comment: @Radostina Zaykova This would work with a string value. I have two columns so the query would look like this in the case of using the BETWEEN clause, (which didn't show the exact solution for my problem):
SELECT Id FROM Table1 WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN Start AND End

Answer (score 1):

TRY

```
SELECT Id FROM Table1 WHERE 
         CONVERT(varchar(16),GETDATE(),121) BETWEEN 
                  CONVERT(varchar(16),[Start], 121) 
                  AND 
                  CONVERT(varchar(16),[END],121);
```

Example of rounding without strings

```
DECLARE @GetDateMinutes as datetime2;

DECLARE @X as datetime2 = getdate();

--round to minutes, could be made into a function
SET @GetDateMinutes = dateadd(minute,datepart(minute,@x),dateadd(hour, datepart(hour,@x),cast(CAST(@x as date) as datetime2)))

select @x, @GetDateMinutes
```

Comment: Seems like a possible solution. I will test it out and return with an answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Truncate the seconds using the technique [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43124298/1186165) to avoid all string conversions, then just do your comparison. Here's a fully contained example that uses `cross apply` and `values` to encapsulate the truncation logic for start and end:

```
-- truncate minutes from current date time
declare @currentDateTime datetime2(0) = DateAdd(minute, DateDiff(minute, 0, Convert(datetime2(0), N'2018-10-01 23:58:32.912')), 0);

select @currentDateTime as CurrentDateTime
     , a.*
from (values -- create a table of dummy values
    (Convert(datetime2(3), N'2018-10-01 19:48:14.735'), Convert(datetime2(3), N'2018-10-10 02:00:00.000'))
  , (Convert(datetime2(3), N'2018-10-01 22:43:19.532'), Convert(datetime2(3), N'2018-11-01 12:17:26.663'))
) as a (StartDateTime, EndDateTime)
cross apply (values(
    -- truncate minutes from start date time
    DateAdd(minute, DateDiff(minute, 0, Convert(datetime2(0), a.StartDateTime)), 0)
    -- truncate minutes from end date time
  , DateAdd(minute, DateDiff(minute, 0, Convert(datetime2(0), a.EndDateTime)), 0)
)) as b (StartDateTimeWithoutSeconds, EndDateTimeWithoutSeconds)
where @currentDateTime between b.StartDateTimeWithoutSeconds and b.EndDateTimeWithoutSeconds;
```

Your data appears to already have the s/ms truncated from start and end but figured I'd apply the same logic to all values involved just to be consistent. Here's the formula for stripping s/ms without all the "noise" from the example:

```
DateAdd(minute, DateDiff(minute, 0, Convert(datetime2(0), <SomeDateTime>)), 0)
```

Comment: Seems like a complex but a full solution. I will test it out and return with an answer. Thank you